# On OS X, with SLIME, inferior lisp stopped when loading foreign libraries

Tags: common-lisp, ffi, slime, quicklisp, clsql

I use Quicklisp to load systems, and I debug my code with Slime. Quicklisp loads many systems successfully except cl-postgresql.

When evaluating `(ql:quickload "clsql-postgresql")` in slime, the inferior lisp exits.

Slime prints

```
Lisp connection closed unexpectedly: connection broken by remote peer
```

in minibuffer and

```
Process inferior-lisp trace/BPT trap: 5
```

in *inferior-lisp* buffer.

But evaluating (ql:quickload "clsql-postgresql") in SBCL without Slime won't cause any error.

I have searched "trace/BPT trap: 5" with Google. The message seems indicating problems in loading dynamic libraries. I suppose the error is caused by wrong search paths set by Slime. According to http://clsql.b9.com/manual/appendix.html, I checked `CLSQL:*FOREIGN-LIBRARY-SEARCH-PATHS*` in bare SBCL and Slime environment, but they were both `nil`.

Why did clsql-postgresql fail to be load when using Slime?

Environment:

- SBCL 1.1.8
- OS X 10.8.4
- latest quicklisp
- latest slime
- emacs 24.3

(sorry for my English, I'm not a native speaker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked User Diagnostic Report. And I found the following lines:

```
Thread 7 Crashed:
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8fab52d5 __CFInitialize + 69
1   dyld                            0x00007fff6f56d256
```

So I googled "CoreFoundation". It said that CoreFoundation must be loaded by the main thread, otherwise it would signal SIGTRAP. It's a rule of OS X.

See: [Debugging a crash when a library is opened via dlopen on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414523/debugging-a-crash-when-a-library-is-opened-via-dlopen-on-osx)

In bare SBCL, `ql:quickload` is directly evaluated in the main thread. But under SLIME, forms are evaluated with a separated thread started by SWANK.

The solution is to evaluate `(ql:quickload "clsql-postgresql")` in `*inferior-lisp*`, instead of `*slime-repl*`, when libpg is the first foreign library depending on CoreFoundation to be loaded.